# VB Script Nested dictionary

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, vbscript, nested

I am formatting a json file into dictionary, Not sure where I am going wrong in assigning the child dictionary to the parent, The value is not getting assigned, Here is my code

```vb
Dim ResDictObj , HostDictObj, SiSConObj 
'ResDictObj contains the details from the query object 
'HostDictObj contains the host details
 
Set ResDictObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set HostDictObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

if HostDictObj.item("sname") = ResDictObj.item("_name") Then
    ResDictObj.add "_snapshot_hostName" , HostDictObj.item("_snapshot_hostName")
    ResDictObj.add "_fullyQualifiedTarget" , HostDictObj.item("_fullyQualifiedTarget")      
End if

Set SiSConObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
SiSConObj.add ServerName & "-" & ResDictObj.Item("_id"), ResDictObj
```

When I print the value the SiSConObj dictionary values seems to be empty. Let me know. Appreciate your help, Assume vbscript supports nested dictionaries.

Comment: How are you printing the SiSConObj dictionary values? like `SiSConObj.item(ServerName & "-" & ResDictObj.Item("_id")).item("_fullyQualifiedTarget")` ?

Comment: I was using a for lool to loop it through. for example
For Each Dataele in DataObj
  for each Childele in DataObj(Dataele)
  StrReportData = StrReportData & "Key: " & Dataele & " Value: " & DataObj.item(Dataele) & vbTab
  next
 Next

Comment: for each SiSConObjKey in SiSConObj.Keys : for each ResDictObjKey in SiSConObj(SiSConObjKey).Keys : StrReportData = StrReportData & "Key:" &  ResDictObjKey & ", Value:" & SiSConObj(SiSConObjKey)(ResDictObjKey) & vbCrlf : next :next